# How can i get all the items like src, titles and url from specific page using this code?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

i have been working in a web scraping code in node.js using the npm puppeteer to get the url, image and titles from each news in the page but the only thing i was able to get the url, image and title from the first news.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const brower = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await brower.newPage();
    const url = 'https://es.cointelegraph.com/category/latest';
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'load' });

    const datos = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.categories-page__list'))
        .map( info => ({

            titulo: info.querySelector('.post-preview-item-inline__title').innerText.trim(),
            link:   info.querySelector('.post-preview-item-inline__title-link').href,
            imagen: info.querySelector('.post-preview-item-inline__figure .lazy-image__wrp img ').src
        }))
    )

    console.log(datos);

    await page.close();
    await brower.close();
})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is just one `.categories-page__list` in the page while there are a lot of `.post-preview-list-inline__item` elements.

You `map` over an array returned from `document.querySelectorAll('.categories-page__list')` but the array has just one element, it's right that it run the `map` closure just once.

So, replace

```
document.querySelectorAll('.categories-page__list')
```

with

```
document.querySelectorAll('.post-preview-list-inline__item')
```

and everything works.

Here you can find a [working example](https://puppeteersandbox.com/DUBNFTyB).

Let me know if you need some more help

Comment: thanks NoriSte it works c: but when to debug the code, i can not get all the src images, it only show me the first three and show me something as if it were empty in the other ones:  imagen: '' "

Comment: The images are lazily loaded, so they're loaded only once you scroll to them. To view it in action: go to the site, open up the devltools->network, choose `offline` and then scroll down. You'll see that not all the images are loaded when you land on the page. So, to view them, you first need to scroll down the whole page with Puppeteer. Then, you can retrieve all the images safely.

Comment: Anyway: be aware that all your issues were not related to Puppeteer! CTRL+C all the function you pass to `page.evaluate` and paste it into the `devtools`->`console` right in your browser (in a tab with the `cointelegraph` opened) and take a look at what it returns. You'll discover that it doesn't work even without Puppeteer 